# C# type conflicts only when explicitly referenced

Tags: c#

I have the following code in my project, this compiles and run (seemingly) properly.

```
SpeechClient.StreamingRecognizeStream streamingCall;

[...]

while (await streamingCall.ResponseStream.MoveNext(CancellationToken.None))
{
    [...]
}
```

In visual studio, hovering over `streamingCall.ResponseStream` tells me that it is of type `System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerator<StreamingRecognizeResponse>`. However the following code

```
System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerator<StreamingRecognizeResponse> responseStream = streamingCall.ResponseStream;
while (await responseStream.MoveNext(CancellationToken.None))
{
    [...]
}
```

does not compile with the error:

```
CS0433  The type 'IAsyncEnumerator<T>' exists in both 
'System.Interactive.Async, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=94bc3704cddfc263' 
and 
'mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'
```

Replacing `System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerator<StreamingRecognizeResponse>` by `var` however does fix the error. The following code, compiles and run properly.

```
var responseStream = streamingCall.ResponseStream;
while (await responseStream.MoveNext(CancellationToken.None))
{
    [...]
}
```

Why is the compiler confused when I use the real type, but not when referring it via either `var` or via a property?
How do I modify the code in order to be able to use the type directly, e.g. to take it as a function parameter?

If that matters, I am running this code on iOS with Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: Another type is being accidentally used (this could be with a type that “looks the same, having the same full name, from a different assembly”, which has the case indicated by the error).. ‘var’ still resolves to *a* type.

Comment: Hovering `var responseStream` also shows `System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerator<StreamingRecognizeResponse>`

Comment: Right, but var *resolves to the type of the return from the method which is from one (or the other) assembly - not both*. This type is assembly-qualified and thus not ambiguous. Sounds like there two assemblies are being used across breaking type-moves. It might be as simple as removing the non-core assembly, or perhaps there is a .NET Standard dependency not being met.

Comment: I am not sure I follow you. Isn't type inference done at compile time?
The ResponseStream getter I am using has the following signature `public virtual IAsyncEnumerator<TResponse> ResponseStream { get; }`

Comment: The **fully qualified** type includes the assembly. You are only seeing the full name - explicitly using the type is ambiguous as it could be the same named type from either assembly (usually because of a dependency versioning mismatch). Using a **reference alias** allows selection of the type from specific assembly.. it still wouldn’t resolve the mis-versioned assembly dependencies, but it would resolve the ambiguity of the explicitly specified type.

Comment: **tldr;** search for “IAsyncEnumerator moved assembly” and ensure that a references and transients use compatible versions (where such is defined that the type is only defined in one referenced - direct or transitive -  assembly). I would venture that one of the assemblies is not actually compatible with the .NET Core version used.

Comment: @user2864740 I believe I got what you were saying, thanks for your time. `System.Interactive.Async::System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerator<StreamingRecognizeResponse>` is not the same type as `mscorlib::System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerator<StreamingRecognizeResponse>` and is correctly picked up by the var declaration. Right?

Answer (score 0):

In the project having this compilation error, try removing a reference to `System.Interactive.Async` assembly/package and try recompiling...

Comment: Sadly System.Interactive.Async is as dependency of one of my dependency.

Comment: i see. try getting the latest update of the "intermediary" dependency if it exists. that may potentially solve the conflict (hoping they removed the offending dependency)